# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code

```
def allButMax():
    input_list=[]
    user_input = 0
    num_sum = 0
    max_num = 0

    while user_input != "end":
        input_list.append(float(user_input))
        user_input = input("Enter next number: ")


    input_list = input_list[1:]

    input_list = input_list.sort


    input_listnew = input_list.pop(-1)


    for num in input_list:
     num_sum = num_sum + num

    print("The num of all values except for the maximum value is: ", num_sum)
```

When I run the program, it says

> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'pop'

This program computes the sum of all the values entered except for the maximum value in the series

I do not know where I went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line

```
input_list = input_list.sort
```

`input_list.sort` is not actually being called. You are just storing a reference to the function in `input_list` and consequently nuking the list.

`sort` is an inplace method, it operates on the list itself, rather than returning a new sorted copy of the list (see `sorted`). It returns `None` therefore you should not try to assign from its return value.

replace

```
input_list = input_list.sort
```

with

```
input_list.sort()
```

Comment: Correct, but this question is off-topic and it should be closed. The error was raised just because *a typo*. I'd suggest delete this answer and post a comment instead.